# How many sons and daughters did Karna have?

Tags: mahabharata, karna

It is known that Karna had sons who actively participated in Kurukshetra war. They assisted his father in battle. Arjuna killed one of Karna's sons in front of Karna as a revenge of his son Abhimanyu's death in Padmavyuha.

How many sons and daughters (if any) did Karna have and what are their names?

Comment: A teaser indeed!   I  read some where that Karna had many sons.   All were killed in the battle by the warriors from Pandavas side except one.  One has to search from Bhishma Parva to Salya Parva. :-)@Sarvabhouma

Answer (score 3):

Karna's sons were Vrishasena, Vrishaketu, Banasena, Chitrasena, Satyasena, Sushena, Shatrunjaya, Dvipata and Prasena. All except for Vrishaktu were killed in the war.

Vrishasena was killed by Arjuna on 17th day.
Chitrasena, Sushena, Satyasena were killed by Nakula on 18th day.
Banasena was killed by Bhima on 16th day.

Arjuna killed Shatrunjaya, Vrishasena, and Dvipata. Bhima killed Banasena. Chitrasena, Satyasena, and Sushena were killed by Nakula.

The only remaining son of Karna was Vrishaketu was taken under the patronage of Pandavas after they knew about the truth of Karna's birth and it is said that Pandavas, especially had great affection for Vrishaketu. Vrishaketu also participated in the Ashwamedha Yagna of Yudhisthira where he was killed by his cousin, Arjuna's son Babruvahana was later revived by Krishna.Vrishaketu later became king of Anga and Indraprastha.

So total, Karna had 9 sons and no daughters.